# Code is messed up after new update of firebase plugin in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

After upgrading to newer plugin pf firebase auth and core its showing up error before it was working fab.

problem is in this part:

```
final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (AuthCredential credential) {

      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
        user.getIdToken().then((token) {
        print("Firebase IdToken: " + token);
        centralstate.idToken = token;
      });});


      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
          centralstate.uid = user;
          print("user::::$user");
        });

        setState(() {
          _loadingFlag = 0;
        });
      });

      _showSnackBar("Phone number verification successfull");
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignInGraphQL()));
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
 just use this if anyone got the same issue and it works like charm